# Gstreamer appsink to rtsp server with appsrc as source large latency

Tags: c, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm having pipeline with appsink which pushes samples to appsrc which acts as a source to pipeline created by rtsp server. It works, I can connect to rtsp server and see the streamed video. The problem is latency. For some reason a lot of buffers is queued in the appsrc and the viewed stream has latency of more than two seconds.

I tried to find the source of latency and it looks like the data are started to being read from appsrc source pad after some time from the point the pipeline is started. The delay between the point the pipeline is started and the point data start to be read out from appsrc source pad is then transformed to it's latency.

I found this by reading out how many bytes is queued in appsrc each time I push the buffer to it. This value which I read out is continuously rising for some time. When the read out of data starts the current amout of the bytes stored in appsrc queue stay approximately the same for the rest of the time I stream the video.

Here is my test application which I'm using to test the correct functionality of this design.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsrc.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>

  GMainLoop *loop;
  GstElement *appsink;
  GstElement *appsrc;
  GstElement *appsink_pipeline;

/* Functions below print the Capabilities in a human-friendly format */
static gboolean print_field (GQuark field, const GValue * value, gpointer pfx) {
  gchar *str = gst_value_serialize (value);

  g_print ("%s  %15s: %s\n", (gchar *) pfx, g_quark_to_string (field), str);
  g_free (str);
  return TRUE;
}

static void print_caps (const GstCaps * caps, const gchar * pfx) {
  guint i;

  g_return_if_fail (caps != NULL);

  if (gst_caps_is_any (caps)) {
    g_print ("%sANY\n", pfx);
    return;
  }
  if (gst_caps_is_empty (caps)) {
    g_print ("%sEMPTY\n", pfx);
    return;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < gst_caps_get_size (caps); i++) {
    GstStructure *structure = gst_caps_get_structure (caps, i);

    g_print ("%s%s\n", pfx, gst_structure_get_name (structure));
    gst_structure_foreach (structure, print_field, (gpointer) pfx);
  }
}

/* called when the appsink notifies us that there is a new buffer ready for
 * processing */
static GstFlowReturn
on_new_sample_from_sink (GstElement * elt, void * data)
{
  GstSample *sample;
  GstFlowReturn ret = GST_FLOW_OK;
  guint64 bytes;
 

  /* get the sample from appsink */
  sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample (GST_APP_SINK (elt));
  if(appsrc)
  {

    bytes = gst_app_src_get_current_level_bytes(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc));
    g_print("buffered bytes before push %lu\n", bytes);
    
    ret = gst_app_src_push_sample(GST_APP_SRC (appsrc), sample);
    // bytes = gst_app_src_get_current_level_bytes(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc));
    // if(ret == GST_FLOW_OK)
      // g_print("pushed ok - buffered bytes after push %lu\n", bytes);

  }
  
  gst_sample_unref (sample);
 
  return ret;
}
 
/* called when we get a GstMessage from the source pipeline when we get EOS, we
 * notify the appsrc of it. */
static gboolean
on_source_message (GstBus * bus, GstMessage * message, void * data)
{
  gint percent;
  g_print ("%s\n", __func__);
 
  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (message)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
      g_print ("The source got dry\n");
      gst_app_src_end_of_stream (GST_APP_SRC (appsrc));
      break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
      g_print ("Received error\n");
      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_BUFFERING:
      gst_message_parse_buffering (message, &percent);
      g_print ("Buffering = %d\n", percent);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
 
static GstFlowReturn need_data (GstElement * appsrc_loc,
                    guint length,
                    gpointer udata)
{

  g_print("Need data\n");

  return GST_FLOW_OK;

}

/* this timeout is periodically run to clean up the expired sessions from the
 * pool. This needs to be run explicitly currently but might be done
 * automatically as part of the mainloop. */
static gboolean
timeout (GstRTSPServer * server)
{
  GstRTSPSessionPool *pool;

  pool = gst_rtsp_server_get_session_pool (server);
  gst_rtsp_session_pool_cleanup (pool);
  g_object_unref (pool);

  return TRUE;
}

void clientConnected(GstRTSPServer* server, GstRTSPClient* client, gpointer user)
{
  g_print("%s\n", __func__);
  
}

static void media_state_cb(GstRTSPMedia *media, GstState state)
{

  g_print("media state = %d\n", state);

}


static void
media_construct (GstRTSPMediaFactory * factory, GstRTSPMedia * media,
    gpointer user_data)
{
  GstElement *element;

  g_print("%s\n", __func__);
  /* get the element used for providing the streams of the media */
  element = gst_rtsp_media_get_element (media);

  /* get our appsrc, we named it 'appsrc' with the name property */
  appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name_recurse_up (GST_BIN (element), "appsrc");
  g_signal_connect (appsrc, "need-data",
      G_CALLBACK (need_data), NULL);

  g_signal_connect (media, "new-state",
      G_CALLBACK (media_state_cb), NULL);

  gst_object_unref (element);
}

static void
media_configure (GstRTSPMediaFactory * factory, GstRTSPMedia * media,
    gpointer user_data)
{
  GstPad *pad;
  GstCaps *caps;
  gchar *caps_str;
  GstElement *element;

  g_print("%s\n", __func__);

  /* get the element used for providing the streams of the media */
  element = gst_rtsp_media_get_element (media);

  /* get our appsrc, we named it 'mysrc' with the name property */
  appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name_recurse_up (GST_BIN (element), "appsrc");

  pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (appsink, "sink");
  if(pad)
  {
    g_print("Got pad\n");
    caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps (pad);
    if(caps)
    {
      caps_str = gst_caps_to_string  (caps);
      g_print("Got caps %s\n", caps_str);
      g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsrc), "caps",  caps, NULL);

      gst_caps_unref(caps);
    }
  }

  /* this instructs appsrc that we will be dealing with timed buffer */
  gst_util_set_object_arg (G_OBJECT (appsrc), "format", "time");

  gst_object_unref (element);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
  GstBus *bus;
  GstRTSPServer *server;
  GstRTSPMountPoints *mounts;
  GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory;

  gchar src[] = "nvv4l2camerasrc device=/dev/video0  ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1920, height=1080, format=UYVY, framerate=60/1 ! " 
        " queue max-size-buffers=3 leaky=downstream ! "
        " nvvidconv name=conv ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1280, height=720, format=NV12, framerate=60/1 ! "
        " nvv4l2h264enc control-rate=1  bitrate=8000000 preset-level=1 profile=0 disable-cabac=1 maxperf-enable=1 name=encoder insert-sps-pps=1 insert-vui=1  idrinterval=30 ! "
        " appsink name=appsink sync=false max-buffers=3";


  gchar sink[] = "( appsrc name=appsrc format=3 stream-type=0 is-live=true blocksize=2097152  max-bytes=200000 ! "
                " queue max-size-buffers=3 leaky=no ! "
                " rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 )";
                  
        
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  /* Create pipeline with appsink */
  g_print("Creating pipeline with appsink\n");
  appsink_pipeline = gst_parse_launch (src, NULL);
 
  if (appsink_pipeline == NULL) {
    g_print ("Bad source\n");
    g_main_loop_unref (loop);
    return -1;
  }

  /* to be notified of messages from this pipeline, mostly EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (appsink_pipeline);
  gst_bus_add_watch (bus, (GstBusFunc) on_source_message, appsink_pipeline);
  gst_object_unref (bus);

  /* Create push_buffer callback for appsink */
  g_print("Creating push buffer callback\n");
  appsink = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (appsink_pipeline), "appsink");
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsink), "emit-signals", TRUE, "sync", FALSE, NULL);
  g_signal_connect (appsink, "new-sample",
      G_CALLBACK (on_new_sample_from_sink), NULL);

  /* Create rtsp server with pipeline starting with appsrc */
  g_print("Creating rtsp server\n");
  /* create a server instance */
  server = gst_rtsp_server_new ();

  /* get the mount points for this server, every server has a default object
   * that be used to map uri mount points to media factories */
  mounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points (server);

  /* make a media factory for a test stream. The default media factory can use
   * gst-launch syntax to create pipelines.
   * any launch line works as long as it contains elements named pay%d. Each
   * element with pay%d names will be a stream */
  factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new ();

  gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory, sink);
  gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared(factory, TRUE);

  /* attach the test factory to the /test url */
  gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory (mounts, "/test", factory);

  /* don't need the ref to the mapper anymore */
  g_object_unref (mounts);

  /* attach the server to the default maincontext */
  if (gst_rtsp_server_attach (server, NULL) == 0)
    goto failed;

  /* add a timeout for the session cleanup */
  g_timeout_add_seconds (2, (GSourceFunc) timeout, server);

  g_signal_connect (server, "client-connected",
      G_CALLBACK (clientConnected), NULL);

  /* Create media-constructed callback to get appsrc reference */
  g_print("Creating media-constructed callback\n");

  g_signal_connect (factory, "media-constructed", (GCallback) media_construct,
      NULL);

  g_signal_connect (factory, "media-configure", (GCallback) media_configure,
      NULL);
  /* Push buffers from appsink to appsrc */


  /* start serving, this never stops */ 

  g_print("Running main loop\n");
  
  gst_element_set_state (appsink_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  g_main_loop_run (loop);
  gst_element_set_state (appsink_pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

  return 0;

  /* ERRORS */
failed:
  {
    g_print ("failed to attach the server\n");
    return -1;
  }
}
```

I will appreciate every idea about what can cause this behavior and how to solve this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This latency problem may be due to many reasons but most of the time this problem is due to frames are not in SYNC. There is a lot of data in the queue.

To counter this problem need to test these test cases to find out the real problem.

1. Check the behavior with videotestsrc instead of the camera source.
2. Are you sure that after nvv4l2camerasrc queue is needed what will be the output if you skip the queue element.
3. You can also check with lower resolution input to get something from it.
4. what happened if you use v4l2src instead of nvv4l2camerasrc if your camera soruce is v4l2 complaince.
   Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your hints. So far I have tried your points no. 1, 2 and 3 as I am unable to use v4l2src. Unfortunetely neither of them gave me positive results. One more thing - the latency is not the same and change with every start of the test application.

Comment: So, It looks like just running the pipeline it works fine but when you use it via this src and sink concept from the app not working. I will check your code step by step then if I find anything wrong will let you know ...Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I just tried to use appsink and appsrc (I add udpsink to the sink pipeline string) pipelines without the rtsp server and it works fine. Regarding this I assume the problem is not in appsink or appsrc itself but more in  the way rtsp handles the pipeline. Maybe I start pushing frame bufferes to appsrc too soon but thats just idea.

Comment: I found the issue. In rtsp-stream.c the udpsink sync property is not configured to FALSE and it is TRUE by default. This is causing the issue as I am using live video source and want to process frames as fast as possible. I tried to change it to FALSE and build it and it works now. I don't know if there is a different solution but I haven't found it. I'm not expert on GStreamer so I could overlook something.

Answer (score 0):

Not a satisfactory answer by any means but I've found the issue has been on the receiving side more than gstreamer and/or your code.

I've been using your code base successfully with minimal latency when streamed by QGroundControl but have found the latency issues you described when streaming to VLC. I haven't tried any others out there as QGC fits my application but suggest others do if VLC or another isn't doing it for them.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35598010)